# Help querying Opened Emails not Clicked

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm trying to perform in one only query following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  j.EmailID,
  s.SubscriberKey,
  s.EVENTDATE as 'SENTDATE',
  o.EVENTDATE as 'OPENDATE',
  j.JOBID
FROM [_Job] j
INNER JOIN [_Sent] s ON (j.JobID = s.JobID)
INNER JOIN [_Open] o ON (o.jobID = j.jobID)
where j.jobid not in (
    select distinct
      c.jobid
    from [_Click] c 
    INNER JOIN [_Job] j2 ON (c.JobID = j2.JobID)
)
```

I get an error.
But If I split this query in two separated queries:

```
select distinct
  c.jobid,
  c.SubscriberKey,
  c.EventDate as 'ClickDate',
  j.EmailID
from 
[_Click] c 
INNER JOIN [_Job] j ON (c.JobID = j.JobID)
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 j.EmailID,
 s.SubscriberKey,
 s.EVENTDATE as 'SENTDATE',
 o.EVENTDATE as 'OPENDATE',
 j.JOBID
FROM [_Job] j
INNER JOIN [_Sent] s ON (j.JobID = s.JobID)
INNER JOIN [_Open] o ON (o.jobID = j.jobID)
```

It is working fine.

I have made a workaround and I have created 3 separated queries and that way is working, but I would like to do in one only query.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the primary key on your target data extension?  Your INNER JOINs are greedy, so they'll produce multiple rows.  If your query produces an error, it's likely that you're violating the primary key.   I'd try re-creating your target DE with no primary keys and every column nullable.

Comment: My primary key is formed by emailid,jobid,subscriberkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adam says, you need to pay attention to the primary key on your target table, but I think you're maybe looking for something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    j.EmailID,
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.EVENTDATE as SENTDATE,
    o.EVENTDATE as OPENDATE,
    j.JOBID
FROM
    [_Job] j WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [_Sent] s WITH (NOLOCK
        ON  j.JobID = s.JobID
    INNER JOIN [_Open] o WITH (NOLOCK
        ON  s.jobID = o.jobID AND
            s.ListID = o.ListID AND
            s.BatchID = o.BatchID AND
            s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID
    LEFT JOIN [_Click] c WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON  o.jobID = c.jobID AND
            o.ListID = c.ListID AND
            o.BatchID = c.BatchID AND
            o.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID
WHERE
    c.JobID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of output are you looking to have? This will give you the JobID, SubscriberKey and EvenDate (of the open) for emails opened in the last 30 days, and have not clicked on any of the emails sent out in the last 30 days.

```
Select 
    JobID
  , SubscriberKey
  , EventDate
From _Open 
Where SubscriberID Not In (
    Select 
      SubscriberID 
    From _Click 
    Where 
        DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GetDate()) < 30
)
And DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GetDate()) < 30
```

Comment: In fact I only need the subscriberkey for sending an email. Your code is not valid since I need the _sent.eventdate to calculate the difference since then to now